# Iframe problems with my webpage

Tags: url, iframe

I have some problems with my website, I make an template called index.html (maybe not smart) but now I have the following problem.

When someone go to the site directly it works perfect, but in Google it's a different story. Google displays the URL directly to my contact page.

http: //..............nl/contact.php  when you click on the link, the template (index.html) is not opening with the contact.php. The only thing you see is text.

is there some thing to check if the index.html is included and otherwise add it to the page?

something like:
if(file_exists('index.html'))
    include '0'
else( include'index.html');

or a redirect or something.

Who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect to index.html if contact.php is not loaded in the iframe.

In contact.php :

```
<script>
if(window===window.top)
location.href = 'index.html';
</script>
```